# BrowserStackLocal: running BrowserStackLocal binary from source code

Tags: java, selenium, cmd, windows-10, browserstack

I am trying to run an instance of BrowserStackLocal from Java 7 using Selenium. I am using Windows 10.

I am aware that if you use BrowserStackLocal in Java, you need to run the following line of code in the cmd.exe and have it open:

```
BrowserStackLocal.exe --key <pass_key>
```

But instead of executing it externally, I want to be able to open the command line from the code.

I am also running the BrowserStack code on differing machines, so I want to be able to call the above command relatively (and not use an absolute path).

So I am running this code ((browserStackLocalPath) is the name of the BrowserStackLocal executable object and (key) is the pass key):

```
// Initializing desired capabilities.
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");
caps.setCapability("browser", "Chrome");
caps.setCapability("browser_version", "50.0");
caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
caps.setCapability("os_version", "7");

// Initializing command line parameters...
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("cmd.exe");
cmdLine.addArgument(browserStackLocalPath);
cmdLine.addArgument("--key");
cmdLine.addArgument(key);

DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);

RemoteWebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
    URL(browserStackURL), caps);
```

...and this has merely resulted in a WebDriverException:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [browserstack.local] is set to true but local testing through BrowserStack is not connected. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 870 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'rchen-PC', ip: '192.168.11.105', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
```

Any ideas on what might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the test was initiated before the Local Testing connection could be established. It takes a few seconds (5-10) to successfully establish the connection. I suggest you add a sleep of 10 seconds (Thread.sleep(10000);) after running the execute command.

Alternatively, you can try the Java bindings for BrowserStackLocal available here - https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-local-java . This helps manage the Local Testing binary programatically.